# CV/CC implementation for Cincon CFB600W-110s24 full brick

Tags: power-supply

I am prototyping a 4s9p Li-ion charger using a full-brick DC-DC power converter with 110 V input and 16.8 V output. I have a relatively stable output with filtering caps at the output side, following the manufacturer's datasheet. I also put in a trim pot for trimming down the output voltage from 24 V to 16.8 V as instructed in an application note (below is attachment of the full brick pin layout).

[image: CFB600W-110s24]

After reading resources about using op-amps as comparators by reading values from a shunt resistor, as well as an application note from Vicor about a [CVCC mode implementation](https://www.vicorpower.com/documents/application_notes/an_ConstantCurrent.pdf) for their brick power supply, I have come up with the same idea: using an op-amp for this circuit to drive its trim pin. I designed it as shown below:

Input side:
[image]

Output Side:
[image]

LM10-opamp pinout:
[image]

Current Control module:
[image]

Current Control method from Vicor power:

[image]

When I hook the circuit up the battery (which is at very low charge, at 12.5 V), I can control the output current using the current trim pot, but the current gradually drifts by 0.1-0.2 A each time and does not seem to stop.

There are times that it stays at one value, but that period is about a few minutes, and current keeps going up.

What could be the cause of this, and what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: How long did you wait for it to drift? It could be components temperature tolerance that could be creating the problem

Comment: @VoltageSpike the output current started to drift after about a minute after I turn on the power supply hooked to the battery.
I think you are right about thermal tolerance. After I sprayed refrigerant spray to the shunt resistor, it does decrease output current but it is not significant. However, when I sprayed it to the area where the opamp and resistors located, output current immediately reduced to initial value that we trimmed it to.
Is there any chance that it is related to current loop stability of the circuit as well.

Comment: You need to separate the thermal drift variation from other drift. A good way to test this would be to leave it on until it gets to it's operating temperature. If it gets to its operating temperature and then continues to drift then you have a problem because if the temperature is stable and it continues to drift the drift must be from something else inherent to the circuit. Another thing I don't understand is how you have the voltage and current potentiometers connected to the same pin in the same manner it looks like you wouldn't be able to control constant current and constant voltage

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thank you for your suggestion and sorry for the wrong schematic that I have uploaded ( I have reuploaded the correct wiring and the reference circuit I used from Vicor). I would try to wait until it gets to its operating temp and then further investigate what's happening.